# Total derivative for functions with higher dimensional codomain.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian, multivalued-functions

I've been learning some multivariable calculus and I ran into the concept of total derivative. I think I grasp the idea and I've seen several examples of how to calculate it for functions $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, but I don't quite see how it works when the codomain is different than $\mathbb{R}$. For example, say we have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by:

$$f(x,y,z) = (x+y, z)$$

What would be the total derivative? Would it be in the shape of a matrix, i.e. something like the Jacobian? Browsing some other posts like [Relating the total derivative and the Jacobian matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489871/relating-the-total-derivative-and-the-jacobian-matrix) (albeit still with codomain $\mathbb{R}$) they're not quite the same thing, so would it just be applying the Jacobian to a random element of $\mathbb{R}^3$ like in the reply to that post?

As a follow up, for the one dimensional case I've seen total derivatives calculated when the variables are all a function of some parameter, how would that work in the multivariable case? Picking the example above, lets say we have a function $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x,y)=xy$. What would be the total derivative of $f(x,y,g(x,y))$ in terms of $x$?

I've tried to find sources online, but most stick with the 1 dimensional codomain, so if you have any sources that would help clarify this for me I would also appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "total derivative". What you call "total" derivative is just **the** derivative of a function between to vector spaces of arbitrary dimension, what is normally called simply $df$. Let me clarify what I mean. 
Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$. We define the derivative, $df(a)$, to be the unique linear map $df(a): \mathbb{R}^M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ such that $$f(a+h)-f(a)=df(a)[h]+o(|h|)$$
for every $h \in \mathbb{R}^M$. This essencially means that $df(a)$ is the best linear approximation of $f$ at $a$. Why do I call this **the** derivative? Because the definition of derivative is, always, that of the best linear approximation of a function at a point. For real functions of real variables, this is obscured by the fact that the linear maps are just scalar multiplications, so the derivative ends up being almost indistinguishable from a number. 
 How does this relate to the Jacobian? Well, you learned, hopefully, in Linear Algebra, that linear maps can be **represented** by matrices, with a suitable choice of basis. The jacobian matrix is just the matrix representing $df(a)$ when you choose the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^M$. 
 So, taking your first example, its derivative, or what you called total derivative, is the map that does this: $$df(a)[(h_1,h_2,h_3)]=(h_1+h_2,h_3)$$ You'll notice that this is just the function $f$; well of course it is! The function was linear to begin with; of course the best linear approximation will be itself. You can also choose the canonical basis and write the Jacobian matrix : $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1&0 \\ 0&0& 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
 As for your other function, let's go through it. Here we have to tread carefuly. After you compose $f$ with $g$, your new function $f^*=f \circ G$ is no longer a function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($G(x,y)=(x,y,g(x,y))$ ). The answer to your question lies in the chain rule; what does it tell us? It tells us that the derivative of the composition of two functions is the composition of their derivatives. So the total derivative of $f \circ G$ is $df dG[h]$. This is better calculated in terms of matrices. The Jacobian of G is $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\\ y&x \end{pmatrix}$$ After composing both matrices you get $$\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1 \\ y &x \end{pmatrix}$$ That is to say, $$d(f \circ G)(x,y)[(h_1,h_2)]=(h_1+h_2,xh_1+yh_2)$$ 
 If you instead mean the total derivative with respect to $x$, like in $\frac{d}{dx}$that's a different story. The total derivative that was mentioned in the post you linked is the kind of derivative I just described. If you want to know about that one, let me know and I'll edit this answer or make a new question and tag me. But they are different things and should not be confused (in fact, that "total derivative" is a special case of the derivative of a composite of functions).

Comment: Much clearer now! As for the second case, I do mean $\frac{d}{dx}$, unrelated to the linked post. You mention them being different things, but are both referred to as "total derivatives" or did I misused the term? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Alooffi they are in fact different things, although in my opinion in the "d/dx" case the usage of the name "total derivative" is much more absurd. I'll refer you to an answer I made previously today; if you're insatisfied I can make an edit to this answer, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4703777/959336

Comment: But anyway the short answer to that question is that it doesn't make sense to talk about the "total" derivative with respect to $x$ of that last function, hopefully the answer I linked will make clear why.

Comment: I think I understand from the explanation you linked, thanks! Slightly related, but given this, what do you think an exercise that asks for the "total derivatives" of a function $f$ similar to the one I wrote in the OP in terms of $x$ and $y$ is actually asking for then?

Comment: @Alooffi they are most likely asking for the derivative I described in this post, that is **the** derivative, the linear map, for every $x,y$. The reason some sources refer to it as the total derivative has most likely to do with the fact that in contrast with the partial derivatives of the function, it has all the information about the differentiability of the function. Furthermore, you can recover any directional derivative with that derivative (it is by definition the image of the derivative on some vector). So it's probably refering to that one.